# Does IntelliJ have the feature equivalent to 'data tips' in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, ide, intellij-14

Visual studio has a feature that goes by the name of 'data tips'.

It allows variables to be pinned, so that the value of variables can be viewed during debugging sessions.

Is this feature available in IntelliJ Idea?

[Image from Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/media/dbg-tips-data-tips-pinned.png?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0):

It's called [an object label](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-labels-to-variables-objects-and-watches.html) in intellij